# Laravel failing now that I moved to public address

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I developed a project using laravel and the php artisan serve. Everything was working as expected.  I have since installed apache and have the apache webserver pointed to my laravel project.  I am pretty sure the webserver config is good because if I make the DocRoot point to non-laravel web pages, it works fine.  When i goto the main page I get the following error.  I am sorry its a mess, I tried to format a bit for clarity.

What other information would you need to help figure this out?

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of 
Illuminate\\myDirr\\myDirr::offsetGet() 
must be an instance of Illuminate\\myDirr\\mixed, 
instance of Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher returned in     
/Users/bmueller/laravel/projectManager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/myDirr/myDirr.php:1417\nStack trace:\n#0
 /Users/bmueller/laravel/projectManager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php(43): 
Illuminate\\myDirr\\myDirr->offsetGet('events')\n#1 
/Users/bmueller/laravel/projectManager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/myDirr/myDirr.php(873): 
Illuminate\\Routing\\RoutingServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array)\n#2 
/Users/bmueller/laravel/projectManager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/myDirr/myDirr.php(758): 
Illuminate\\myDirr\\myDirr->build(Object(Closure))\n#3 /Users/bmueller/laravel/projectManager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(855): 
Illuminate\\myDirr\\myDir in /Users/bmueller/laravel/projectManager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/myDirr/myDirr.php on line 1417
```

Here is the apache log of a request:

```
[Thu Mar 03 13:51:31.554405 2022] [:debug] [pid 45104] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 192.168.183.1:60670] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths / vs /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/, related=1
[Thu Mar 03 13:51:31.554412 2022] [:debug] [pid 45104] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 192.168.183.1:60670] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/ vs /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/, related=0
[Thu Mar 03 13:51:31.554418 2022] [:debug] [pid 45104] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 192.168.183.1:60670] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths /usr/share/httpd/icons/ vs /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/, related=0
[Thu Mar 03 13:51:31.554425 2022] [:debug] [pid 45104] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 192.168.183.1:60670] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/ vs /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/, related=1
[Thu Mar 03 13:51:31.554431 2022] [:debug] [pid 45104] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 192.168.183.1:60670] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths .*\\.\\.namedfork/ vs /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/, related=0
[Thu Mar 03 13:51:31.554437 2022] [:debug] [pid 45104] mod_hfs_apple2.c(384): [client 192.168.183.1:60670] mod_hfs_apple: Final check compares: /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/ vs /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/, length 45
[Thu Mar 03 13:51:31.554444 2022] [:debug] [pid 45104] mod_hfs_apple2.c(397): [client 192.168.183.1:60670] mod_hfs_apple: Allowing access with matching directory. filename = /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/
[Thu Mar 03 13:51:31.554515 2022] [:debug] [pid 45104] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 192.168.183.1:60670] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths / vs /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/index.php/, related=1
[Thu Mar 03 13:51:31.554527 2022] [:debug] [pid 45104] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 192.168.183.1:60670] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/ vs /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/index.php/, related=0
[Thu Mar 03 13:51:31.554534 2022] [:debug] [pid 45104] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 192.168.183.1:60670] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths /usr/share/httpd/icons/ vs /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/index.php/, related=0
[Thu Mar 03 13:51:31.554541 2022] [:debug] [pid 45104] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 192.168.183.1:60670] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/ vs /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/index.php/, related=1
[Thu Mar 03 13:51:31.554547 2022] [:debug] [pid 45104] mod_hfs_apple2.c(363): [client 192.168.183.1:60670] mod_hfs_apple: compare_paths .*\\.\\.namedfork/ vs /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/index.php/, related=0
[Thu Mar 03 13:51:31.554553 2022] [:debug] [pid 45104] mod_hfs_apple2.c(384): [client 192.168.183.1:60670] mod_hfs_apple: Final check compares: /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/index.php vs /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/, length 45
[Thu Mar 03 13:51:31.554560 2022] [:debug] [pid 45104] mod_hfs_apple2.c(397): [client 192.168.183.1:60670] mod_hfs_apple: Allowing access with matching directory. filename = /Users/myDir/laravel/projectManager/public/index.php
```

Removed vendor directory,  ran ./composer install

now i get

```
Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2".
```

my php -v

```
PHP 8.1.3 (cli) (built: Mar  1 2022 01:17:32) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.1.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^8.0.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0.5",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^9.0",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.4",
    "psr/container": "1.0.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
    "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    },
    "files": ["app/Ubersmith/devClient.php",
        "app/Ubersmith/client.php"]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
}
```

Im aware of myDirr vs MyDir.  I copy/pasted to remove personal info.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242585/discussion-on-question-by-bart2puck-laravel-failing-now-that-i-moved-to-public-a).

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same the same problem.
The issue is php version requirements difference.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31740269)

Answer (score 0):

From you terminal do this:

`a2enmod php8.0`

then

`sudo service apache2 restart`

then

`php artisan key:generate`

that was the procedure